# connect to kafka ssl using pyspark ( javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Unexpected handshake message: server_hello )

Tags: python, apache-spark, ssl, pyspark, apache-kafka

i want to connect to kafka using pyspark using ssl/tls but i got an error even if **i did add the certificate to the java truststore**.

I tried the following code

```
import os  
os.environ["JAVA_OPTS"] = "-Djavax.net.debug=ssl" 
import logging 
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG) 
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession 
spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.jars.packages", 
        'org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2,org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.2.1')
        .appName("KafkaSourceExample")
        .getOrCreate() 

 source_id1_options = {     "kafka.bootstrap.servers": bootstrap_servers,     
                            "subscribe": topics,     
                            "kafka.group.id": group_id,     
                            "kafka.security.protocol": "SSL",     
                            "ssl.key.location": "kafka.key",     
                            "ssl.certificate.location": "kafka.crt",     
                            "ssl.ca.location": "kafka.crt",     
                            "startingOffsets": "earliest"
                         }  
df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").options(**source_id1_options).load() 
query = df.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").start()
```

but i get the following errors :

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: SSL handshake failed
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Unexpected handshake message: server_hello